# want a .bat file that auto set display properties and background images

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a simple batch file that when executed will

- Open my display properties
- Adjust my screen resolution
- Change my background image

I've got as far as having open the display properties window, but don't know how to make it select and change settings. I may be going about it the wrong way, but I'm really new to this.

Here's my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
START C:\WINDOWS\system32\desk.cpl
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://www.naughter.com/qres.html) software.

and you can change resolution by rundll

`rundll deskcp16.dll,QUICKRES_RUNDLLENTRY 800x600x8`